# spring-boot with liquibase @OneToMany mapping

Tags: spring-boot, database-design, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have two entity `Person` and `Address`. And  `Person` can have multiple `Address`.

```
<createTable tableName="ADDRESS">
            <column name="id" type="bigint(20)" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
               ... //columns
            </column>
</createTable>
```

---

```
<createTable tableName="PERSON">
            <column name="id" type="bigint(20)" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
               ... //columns
            </column>
</createTable>
```

---

```
    <addForeignKeyConstraint
        constraintName="fk_constraint_worker_phone_number"
        referencedTableName="CONTACT_NUMBER" baseColumnNames="ContactNumbers"
        baseTableName="WORKER" referencedColumnNames="id" />
```

I want 3rd table (like hibernate generate in `@OneToMany` mapping).

How to do this with `liquibase-springboot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relation is truly a OnToMany, you don't need a 3rd table. Simply, add PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.

If the address can be reused for many persons, it's a ManyToMany relation.

You can use @ManytoMany and add information about you joined table un @jointable

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case of liquibase we have to create the 3rd table manually and have to apply the necessary constraints.

**Create the table which manages the mapping** :

---

```
<createTable tableName="PERSON_ADDRESS">
    <column name="PERSON_ID" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="ADDRESS_ID" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
</createTable>
```

---

Apply the constraints:

1) Ensure that `Person`s `id` is unique in the mapping table

2) A foreign key relationship between `ADDRESS`'s id and `PERSON_ADDRESS`'s `PERSON_ID`

3) A foreign key relationship between `PERSON`'s id and `PERSON_ADDRESS`'s `ADDRESS_ID`

---

```
<addUniqueConstraint
            columnNames="PERSON_ID" tableName="PERSON_ADDRESS"
            constraintName="UK_PHONE_NUMBERS_ID" />
```

---

```
<addForeignKeyConstraint
            constraintName="FK_ADDRESS_PERSON_ADDRESS"
            referencedTableName="ADDRESS"
            baseColumnNames="ADDRESS_ID"
            baseTableName="PERSON_ADDRESS" referencedColumnNames="id" />
```

---

```
<addForeignKeyConstraint
            constraintName="FK_PERSON_PERSON_ADDRESS"
            referencedTableName="PERSON"
            baseColumnNames="PERSON_ID"
            baseTableName="PERSON_ADDRESS" referencedColumnNames="id" />
```